# How to change button value with slideToggle()

Tags: jquery

I am working on [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/8YVAr/). How can I change the button text with slideToggle() function? I just need to change the text to Show or Hide. What I have is:

```
<button id="boxToggle">Show</button>
<div id="over_map"></div>

$("#boxToggle").click(function(){
    $("#over_map").slideToggle();
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change text with the [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function. So something like this would work:

```
$("#boxToggle").click(function(){
    $("#over_map").slideToggle();
    
    if($(this).text() == 'Hide')
    {
        $(this).text('Show');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).text('Hide');   
    }
});
```

So whenever the text is "Hide" *on click*, the text will change to "Show". And the other way around.

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8YVAr/1/)

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
<button id="boxToggle">Show</button>
<div id="over_map"></div>

$("#boxToggle").click(function(){
    $("#over_map").slideToggle();
    $("#boxToggle").prop('value', 'hide');
  });
```

**or**

```
$("#boxToggle").click(function(){
    $("#over_map").slideToggle();
    $("#boxToggle").text('hide');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Change your button text to "Hide" and use below JS

```
$("#boxToggle").click(function(){
    $("#over_map").slideToggle(function(){
        if($("#over_map").is(':visible')){
            $("#boxToggle").text('Hide')
        }

        else{
            $("#boxToggle").text('Show')
        }
    }); 
});
```